# Can't clean Notification Center without aps badge or badge = 0?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I push to user a notification payload without badge key or badge = 0, the notification can't be removed from Notification Center. Here is my payload:

```
{
     "aps" : {"alert" : "bala bala"}
//or "aps" : {"alert" : "bala bala", "badge" : 0}
}
```

Then open app from NC, the notification stay in NC, can't be removed. If I set badge value greater then 0 in aps, the notification will be removed after app launch.

```
{
    "aps" : {"alert" : "bala bala", "badge" : 1}
}
```

I have **already** set `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];` after app launch.

Why notification can't be removed without badge key or badge = 0 ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using local notification???

Comment: i am using local notification remove all notification by [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

Comment: @SarafarazBabi Thanks for your comment, I'm using remote push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is pretty simple:
Set the Badge first 1 and then 0. That should clear the notifications out of the NC.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
// Now the notification should be cleared out of the NC
```

Answer (score 0):

badge is 0, it's mean "not change". so, you must set -1 for badge.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
```

Comment: Anything `no change`? Even can't be removed from NC?

Comment: i dont know, why it dont work with you. How do you implement?, what is the function used?

Answer (score 0):

From : [iOS 5 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html)

- > Push and local notifications for apps appear in the new Notification
  >   Center in iOS 5. Notification Center displays notifications that are
  >   considered "unread.” To accommodate push and local notifications that
  >   have no unread status, set your application’s badge count to 0 to
  >   clear that app’s notifications from Notification Center.

So the solution is to set the application badge to 0 when the app is opened.